# How to listen to keyboard when app is in background in flutter

Tags: linux, flutter, desktop-application, keyboard-events

I'm trying to listen to keyboard keypress events when the app is in background. This snippet can only listen to keyboard when app is active.

```
var pressedKey = '';
  int count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(_handleKeyPress);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    RawKeyboard.instance.removeListener(_handleKeyPress);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleKeyPress(RawKeyEvent event) {
    setState(() {
      if (event.isControlPressed && event.character != null) {
        pressedKey = 'Ctrl + ${event.character}';
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you make the question more clear like 1) what you want to achieve 2) what you have achieved 3) whole code of that and also pubspec.yaml

Comment: 1. I want to listen to any key press events when the app is in the background
2. Can detect the keypress when app is active
3. `clipboard: ^0.1.3` 

StackOverflow error saying mostly code